# Most elegant way to separate list based on pattern (Python)

Tags: python, list

I have a pandas column of lists of consecutive log actions that users do, while posting a photo in mobile app in each whole logging session. Suppose the single list looks like:

```
my_list = [
      'action_a', 'action_b', 'action_c', 'action_z', 
      'action_j',
      'action_a','action_b', 
      'action_a', 'action_b', 'action_z']
```

1) action_a - the start of photo upload

2) action_z - the end of photo upload

3) other actions_i - all the actions that can occur between action_a and action_z.

4) there may be errors, like 'action_j', that appear not between 'action_a', 'action_z' and we shouldn't take them into account

5) the process of photo upload may not be completed - so there may be path like 'action_a','action_b'.

The GOAL = separate my_list into sublists of all action paths that starts with 'action_a' and ends with 'action_z' or ends before another 'action_a'. So the result should be like that:

```
['action_a', 'action_b', 'action_c', 'action_z'] 
['action_a','action_b']
['action_a', 'action_b', 'action_z']
```

So currently I am trying to solve it like that: firstly I've deleted all my_lists, where the number of 'action_z' is greater than the number of 'action_a' or where there is no 'action_a'. Then I did that:

```
indices_a = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == "action_a"]
indices_z = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == "action_z"]

if(len(indices_z)<1):
    for i_a,x_a in enumerate(indices_a):
        if (i_a+1 != len(indices_a)):
            indices_z.append(indices_a[i_a+1]-1) 
        else: indices_z.append(len(my_list)-1) 
else:       
    for i_a,x_a in enumerate(indices_a):
        if (i_a+1 != len(indices_a)):
            if (indices_z[i_a] > indices_a[i_a+1] ):
                indices_z.insert(i_a, indices_a[i_a+1]-1)
        else:  indices_z.append(len(my_list)-1) 

res=[]
for i,j in zip(indices_a, indices_z):
    res.append(my_list[i:j+1] )
```

Seems like it works. What is the better way?

Answer (score 4):

I've tried to simplify things a little and came up with this logic:

```
result = []
curr_list = None

for item in my_list:
    if item == 'action_a':
        if curr_list is not None:
            # Only append is there is content
            result.append(curr_list)
        # Create a new list
        curr_list = []

    try:
        # Try to append the current item
        curr_list.append(item)

        if item == 'action_z':
            # Close the current list but don't initialize 
            # a new one until we encounter action_a
            result.append(curr_list)
            curr_list = None
    except AttributeError:
        # This means we haven't encountered action_a yet
        # Just ignore and move on
        pass

if curr_list is not None:
    # Append an "open" list if there is one
    result.append(curr_list)

for item in result:
    print(item)
```

Result:

```
['action_a', 'action_b', 'action_c', 'action_z']
['action_a', 'action_b']
['action_a', 'action_b', 'action_z']
```

Comment: Thank you, @Kristof. Seems like the [ 'action_a', 'action_b','action_a'] doesn't return correct result

Comment: @AntonMashikhin Correct, I've update the code to handle that case as well.

Comment: looks nice!  Way cleaner than with indexes.

Answer (score 3):

With the rules:

- endswith a: start new list unless last one is empty and add a to it
- endswith z: add to previous list, then start new list
- else: add to previous list unless it is empty

Note that this would allow for lists of `action_z` by themselves if `and sublists[-1]` is removed from the `z` code.

```
sublists=[[]]
for li in my_list:
    if li[-1]=='a':
        if sublists[-1]:
            sublists.append([li])
        else:
            sublists[-1].append(li)
    elif li[-1]=='z' and sublists[-1]:
        sublists[-1].append(li)
        sublists.append([])
    elif sublists[-1]:
        sublists[-1].append(li)

if not sublists[-1]:
   sublists.pop()
```

Would print:

```
[['action_a', 'action_b', 'action_c', 'action_z'], 
 ['action_a', 'action_b'], 
 ['action_a', 'action_b']]
```

`li[-1]=="[letter]"` could always be replaced with `li=="action_[letter]"` if desirable.

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite opinion based. But if functional applies to your notion of elegance I would suggest to use some kind of partitioning algorithm like a group by or partition by.

There are different styles of this kind of higher order function, but the basic idea is quite simple, you get a stream or list of elements and you provide a function that tells the algorithm whether an element should be considered an element where a new list starts (I would call it a partition point). I personally think that adding a layer of nesting in your data structure looks cleaner. i.e. you make a function that gets a list and it returns a list of lists.

```
# function that defines the start of a new sequence
def partition_begin(photo_action):
    return photo_action is 'action_a'

# function that defines the end of a new sequence
def partition_end(photo_action):
    return photo_action is 'action_z'

# get a list of elements and define a starting and stopping function
# and return a list of lists separated by start and stop.
def partition_by(elements, partition_separator, partition_terminator):
    partitioned_stream = []
    for element in elements:
        if partition_separator(element):
            # start a new list and append it to the stream.
            partitioned_stream.append([element])
            continue
        if partition_terminator(element):
            # add element to the last sequence, but start a new list. 
            partitioned_stream[-1].append(element)
            partitioned_stream.append([])
            continue
        # standard append to list.
        partitioned_stream[-1].append(element)
    return partitioned_stream


my_list = [
      'action_a', 'action_b', 'action_c', 'action_z',
      'action_j',
      'action_a','action_b',
      'action_a', 'action_b', 'action_z']

print partition_by(my_list, partition_begin, partition_end)

# [
#   ['action_a', 'action_b', 'action_c', 'action_z'],
#   ['action_j'],
#   ['action_a', 'action_b'],
#   ['action_a', 'action_b', 'action_z'],
#   []
# ]
```

If you have functional programming languages this becomes more interesting as often these kind of algorithms allow you to nest different functions into the algorithm. You probably have noticed that this code returns an empty list at the end which might look weird, but you can get rid of this by applying a list comprehension or simply filtering empty elements.

```
# remove empty elements from a list
non_empty = lambda x: len(x) > 0
filter(non_empty, partition_by(my_list, partition_begin, partition_end))
```

Comment: as a side note: haskell chose to implement this using one function taking two arguments, and if the function returns false it'll split the list between the two. this saves a function and makes this a bit more versatile, but may make it not applicable in as many cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should first split the list based on the indexes of **'action_a'**, then remove all actions appearing after **'action_z'** as follows:

```
 import itertools
 def process_actions(actions,action_first='action_a',action_last='action_z'):
  '''Split the list based on action_a'''
  _actions = [[action_first]+list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(l,lambda x:x==action_first) if not k]
  '''Remove all actions appearing after action_z'''
  _actions = [x[0:x.index(action_last)+1] if action_last in x else x for x in _actions ]
  return _actions
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing the representation of the problem, I think you could simplify the solution.

How about changing the data representation from text to numbers and keep the map in a dictionary?
Something akin to:

```
my_dict = {
  'action_a': 0,
  'action_b': 1,
  'action_c': 2,
  'action_z': 255, 
  'action_j': -1 ## and all the other values you want to dump
}
```

You can then separate your problem into two parts:

- filtering out all the negative values
- breaking the list up to ascending order sub-lists.

the second part solves about like this:

```
[[z for z in y]
for x,y in 
itertools.groupby(
    itertools.zip_longest(
        map(
            lambda x: x[1]-x[0] > 0, 
            itertools.zip_longest(
                num_list,num_list[1:],fillvalue=0)
            ),num_list,
        fillvalue=True),
    lambda x: x[0])]
```

Where num_list is a list of integers >= 0

- compute the running diff between pairs of elements in the list and mark True if > 0
- zip it with the original list
- Group by True's
- Unfurl the groupby operation

From the final list that's returned you'll need to do some more processing, like taking pairs to get the full list, but this should produce a workable solution. 
It could be written a bit more elegantly, but I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that begins a new sublist on any item in parameter `first`, and ends the sublist on any item in parameter in `last`.  It returns a generator for efficiency.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Iterable

def list_breaker(input_list, first, last, keep_orphans=False):
    '''
    Breaks a list, `x`, into a list of sub elements.

    input_list : list
        The list of items to be split into sublists
    first : item or list of items
        The item/items that identify the start of a new sublist
    last : item or list of items
        The item/items that identify the end of a sublist
    keep_orphans : bool
        When `True`, all sublists are returned.  When `False`,
        only sublists that have a zeroth element in `first` or 
        a last element in `last` are returned.
    '''
    # convert inputs to lists
    if isinstance(first, str) or not isinstance(first, Iterable):
        first = [first]
    if isinstance(last, str) or not isinstance(last, Iterable):
        last = [last]

    # find the places to break the list.  
    breaks = [(lambda i,x: i if x in first else i+1)(i,x) 
              for i,x in enumerate(input_list) if x in chain(first, last)] + [None]
    # slice the list according to the breaks
    for i in range(len(breaks)-1):
        out = input_list[slice(*breaks[i:i+2])] 
        if keep_orphans and out:
            yield out
        if not keep_orphans and out:
            if out[0] in first or out[-1] in last:
                yield out
```

Tests:

```
# note I added an additional action to the end
my_list = [
      'action_a', 'action_b', 'action_c', 'action_z', 'action_j',
      'action_a','action_b', 'action_a', 'action_b', 'action_z', 'action_d']

list_breaker(my_list, 'action_a', 'action_z')
# returns:
[['action_a', 'action_b', 'action_c', 'action_z'],
 ['action_a', 'action_b'],
 ['action_a', 'action_b', 'action_z']]

list_breaker(my_list, 'action_a', 'action_z', True)
# returns:
[['action_a', 'action_b', 'action_c', 'action_z'],
 ['action_j'],
 ['action_a', 'action_b'],
 ['action_a', 'action_b', 'action_z'],
 ['action_d']]
```

Start a new list when either `'action_a'` or `'action_c'` is encountered.

```
list(list_breaker(my_list, ['action_a', 'action_c'], 'action_z'))
# returns:
[['action_a', 'action_b'],
 ['action_c', 'action_z'],
 ['action_a', 'action_b'],
 ['action_a', 'action_b', 'action_z']]
```

End a sublist when either `'action_z'` or `'action_c'` is encountered.

```
list(list_breaker(my_list, 'action_a', ['action_c', 'action_z']))
# returns:
[['action_a', 'action_b', 'action_c'],
 ['action_z'],
 ['action_a', 'action_b'],
 ['action_a', 'action_b', 'action_z']]
```